# Why is first element of multi dimensional Array not showing in for loop but can be accessed by myArray.get(0,0,0)?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

```
 for ( String s : strNdArr ) {
      System.out.println("s: " + s);
      // skips first element
    }
    System.out.println(strNdArr.get(0,0,0));
    // prints first element
```

Why is the first element not showing up in the for loop iteration but can be accessed separately with get?

Comment: Whatever `strNdArr` is could implement the iterator in any way it wants, skipping the first entry, every prime entry, a random entry, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, whatever the type of `strNdArr` is, it is NOT a Java array.  If it was, `strNdArr.get(0, 0, 0)` would be a compilation error.  Java array types don't have an `get` methods.

So ... it must be some Java class.  That means that the behavior of the `for` loop will depend on how that class implements its `iterator()` method.

> Why is first element of multi dimensional Array not showing in for loop ...

Because that is what the `Iterator` returned by `iterator()` has been implemented to do.

Why?

You would need to look at its documentation or source code to figure that out.

<sup>(I cannot tell you more unless you tell us more about the class that you are using there.  I am pretty confident that it is not a standard Java SE class, but there aren't any other clues to aid a search.)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It was a stupid mistake on my part, I had implemented an iterator that didn't start from 0 but from 1